# Curiosity: why an externalized document builds faster and in a single pass?

Tags: import

It could be just me being enthusiastic about completing the externalization of a sizable book into the separate chapters by way of using `import` package, but I get a distinct impression that the document now compiles at least 2-3 times faster and in a single pass instead of two passes. Does this make sense and why?

`pdflatex` is used for building and the total size of the source code is 1.1 MB. It now resides in 10 files.

Answer (score 1):

`\import` isn't externalisation in the sense of tikz externalization which includes pre-made images as pdf rather than re-doing the calculation each time, it is simply a very thin wrapper around `\input` just adjusting the file search logic slightly. As such using it can not be faster than using `\input` or simply including the text in the same source file.

Comment: Then it could be something TexStudio does behind the scenes. I timed the compilation and it is indeed 2-3 times faster now - like 3 seconds vs 7-9 seconds after I hit F1 in the studio.

Answer (score 1):

The key point in the question is "a single pass instead of two passes".

In general you need to do multiple passes to correctly resolve cross references, rebuild the index, etc.

Either you are now only making "small" edits which don't force multiple compilations, or somehow you told TexStudio not to do them anyway, since there might not be much point until you get close to a stable version of the document.

I don't use TexStudio, so I have no idea about the specifics of how to control it.

Comment: As I did not tinker with TexStudio settings, it is hard to tell. But you must be onto something, as now all index-related commands live in the main file and I am only really editing the imported chapters.